# Add OpenCV 3.0 pod to Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, cocoapods

I added OpenCV 3.0 pod to xcode project using below command in my pod file

```
pod 'OpenCV', '~> 3.0'
```

and installed the pod successfully. But when I go to import OpenCV in my .swift file it says "No such module 'OpenCV'".

How I imported OpenCV

```
import OpenCV
```

This is the error I am getting

[image]

If this is not the correct way to import OpenCV or any other thing I am doing wrong, please help me to get rid of it. This is my first time I use OpenCV in an Xcode project specially with cocoapods. Please can someone help me to get my work done. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you have your answer in another question [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735545/xcode-7-does-not-build-project-with-c-framework). You have to use a bridging header and a wrapper - as the library uses C++ code.

Comment: Thanks @lonut. Will have a look on it. (Y)