# How can I check if a llvm instruction is inside a loop?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have a filtered set of instructions with in a llvm pass. I want to check if each instruction is a part of any loop ( or sub loops). I know that I can get the parent basic block from an instruction

```
BasicBlock* bb = aInst->getParent();
```

But how to check if the instruction / the basic block is part of a loop or not ?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32927051/8925535)

Comment: That is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [LoopInfo](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoopInfo.html) to find loops in an `llvm::Function`.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32927051/8925535), you can get the function a given instruction belongs to, compute a dominator tree for that function, and analyze the result with an `llvm::LoopInfo::BaseT` object.

```c++
llvm::DominatorTree DT = llvm::DominatorTree();
DT.recalculate(instr->getFunction());
auto loopInfo = new llvm::LoopInfoBase<llvm::BasicBlock, llvm::Loop>();
loopInfo->releaseMemory();
loopInfo->analyze(DT);
```

Then you check if `instr` 's surrounding function contains a loop that contains `instr` by passing `instr` and `loopInfo` to a routine like

```c++
bool instrIsInaLoop(llvm::LoopInfoBase<llvm::BasicBlock, llvm::Loop> &loopInfo,
                    llvm::Instruction *instr) {
    for (auto loop : loopInfo) if (instrIsInLoop(loop, instr)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

with subroutine

```c++
bool instrIsInLoop(llvm::Loop *loop, llvm::Instruction *instr) {
    if (loop->contains(instr))
        return true;

    else {
        for (auto subLoop : loop->getSubLoops()) {
            if (instrIsInLoop(loop, instr)) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do we have to use dominator tree ? We can get LoopInfo directly in a module pass like this :  LoopInfo &LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>().getLoopInfo(); .  Am I missing something ?

Comment: That will also work. But since it's a module pass you'd instead want `LoopInfo &LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>(F).getLoopInfo()`

Comment: @droptop Hello, I'm just curious, what does `res = res || instrIsInLoop(subLoop, instr);` actually do? I believe it is a recursion to iterate through subLoop, but I'm not too sure what is the point of `res = res`. Could you please let me know what this technique is? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Jay Hi. You can think of `instrIsInLoop` as a depth first search for `instr` starting at `loop`. I'm not quite sure of the technique you're referring to.

Comment: @droptop thank you for your response; the "technique" I was referring to was regarding the one-liner technique used for the `for` loop. Why is `res = res` necessary? I sincerely apologize in advance, but what would it be like if you were to *expand* that one-liner?

`for (auto subLoop : loop->getSubLoops()) {
  if (res == res) 
    continue
  else 
    instrIsInLoop(subLoop, instr);
}`

Like this? I apologize if my question is a bit weird, and thank you in advance.

Comment: @Jay I've modified the code to exit the loop once `instr` is found. That should clear things up.

Comment: @droptop ah! Thank you so much! Really appreciate it.